# Typescript Maximum call stack size exceeded Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, material-ui, callstack

I am having this error with my code here is the full error message:

```
[internal]
TypeScript error in [internal](undefined,undefined):
Maximum call stack size exceeded  TSINTERNAL_ERROR
```

When I `npm start` my app it is normaly working for few secs then the error come up. It is failing after :

```
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
```

Since there is no detail I have no idea what is the problem itself.

I put a breakpoint where the error pops up but it is just and event catcher and I can not see the full stack.

Here is the packages I use:

```
+-- @material-ui/core@4.11.0
+-- @material-ui/icons@4.9.1
+-- @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56
+-- @reduxjs/toolkit@1.4.0
+-- @types/jest@24.0.12
+-- @types/node@11.13.8
+-- @types/ol@6.3.1
+-- @types/react@16.8.15
+-- @types/react-dom@16.8.4
+-- @types/react-redux@7.1.9
+-- @types/react-router-dom@5.1.5
+-- axios@0.19.2
+-- immer@7.0.5
+-- json-server@0.16.1
+-- jsonwebtoken@8.5.1
+-- ol@6.3.1
+-- react@16.13.1
+-- react-dom@16.13.1
+-- react-hook-form@6.0.4
+-- react-redux@7.2.0
+-- react-router-dom@5.2.0
+-- react-scripts@3.0.0
+-- redux@4.0.5
+-- redux-devtools-extension@2.13.8
+-- redux-thunk@2.3.0
+-- redux-toolkit@1.1.2
+-- typescript@3.9.5
```

How can I catch the problem?

Thx

Comment: The error looks like an infinite recursion. Do you have code with a function that calls itself somewhere? make you that has an exit condition so recursion is not endless. You also say it works for a few seconds, what happens after a few seconds when using your app? do you have a setTimeout/setInterval call somewhere for example that could start running some code a few seconds later? some ajax request to an API that might be too slow? check things like that

Comment: This does not depend on the packages in use, but there is something in your code that keeps calling a function recusively. I would look for an infinite chain of callbacks/events or a recursive function without termination check

Comment: This is an internal error. Seems more like a typescript error than a application code error. I also started getting these errors after I switched to material ui. Probably their type code has some definition loop that leads to this error.